# Simple ORM Structure Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, properties, undefined

This is my code:

```
<?php

class VortexORM {

    private static $orm = null;

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (VortexORM::$orm == null)
            VortexORM::$orm = new VortexORM();
        return VortexORM::$orm;
    }

    public static function set($name, $value) {
        $orm = VortexORM::getInstance();
        //echo "Setting [ <b>{$name}</b> ::   <i>{$value}</i>]";
        $orm->$name = $value;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        $orm = VortexORM::getInstance();
        // echo "Getting [ <b>{$name}</b> ::   <i>{$orm->$name}</i>]";
        return $orm->$name;
    }

}
```

To get data I use:

```
var_dump(VortexORM::get('admin_links'));
var_dump(VortexORM::get('admin'));
```

To set data I use:

```
VortexORM::set('admin_links',array(....));
```

However, I get the following warnings:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: VortexORM::$admin_links
Filename: Vortex/VortexORM.php
Line Number: 8
NULL
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: VortexORM::$admin
Filename: Vortex/VortexORM.php
Line Number: 8
```

Why am I getting these warnings?

I want to be able to access it like this in CodeIgniter as a static function:

```
$this->vortexorm->admin_links = array(....);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I just tested this code:

```
    <?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

class VortexORM {

    private static $orm = null;

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (VortexORM::$orm == null)
            VortexORM::$orm = new VortexORM();
        return VortexORM::$orm;
    }

    public static function set($name, $value) {
        $orm = VortexORM::getInstance();
        //echo "Setting [ <b>{$name}</b> ::   <i>{$value}</i>]";
        $orm->$name = $value;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        $orm = VortexORM::getInstance();
        // echo "Getting [ <b>{$name}</b> ::   <i>{$orm->$name}</i>]";
        return $orm->$name;
    }

}

VortexORM::set('admin_links',"test");

var_dump(VortexORM::get('admin_links'));
```

It just worked fine for me. giving the following output:

```
string(4) "test"
```

So, I guess, you were might just trying to retrieve a property before its set? Or please share  more details. Also, why are you trying to create new ORM, where we can [use doctrine with codeigniter](http://codesamplez.com/development/using-doctrine-with-codeigniter) easily?